# Github pages, image's wont load - the server responded with a 404 for the image retrieval

Tags: github, github-pages

[[image: 404 Error:[1]]

I published my Github pages with the **docs folder on master branch** option.
Here's my repo:

https://github.com/mattfrancis888/portfolio

Here's my Github pages:

https://mattfrancis888.github.io/portfolio/

I have tried:

- Checking for img src's case sensitivity.
- Put images in the **docs** folder

Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: View Source is your friend. Use it to look at the HTML source of your page to see if the `src` attributes of your `<img ... >` tags are what you expect.

Comment: Yes! it is exactly what i expect! here's my github pages! https://mattfrancis888.github.io/portfolio/         I also added my repo above!

Comment: It works now! it just took a very long time for the images to upload!! But for future references, do you need to put your images in your docs file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github Pages took about an hour for the images to upload! it works fine now!